# Series. Precise definition of the Direct Comparison Test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n} $$

I see direct comparison:

$$ \frac{\ln(n)}{n} > \frac{1}{n} \qquad (\text{for } n>2) $$

But, this is not true, since $\ln x >1$ only when $x>e = 2.71$

So, for $n = 2.5$, it's not greater.

So, what is the exact definition of the direct comparison test?  The inequality only needs to hold for sufficiently large values of $n$?

Comment: One can define it in various ways. Defining it so that the inequality is required to hold for $n \geqslant N$ with an arbitrary $N\in \mathbb{N}$ is most convenient, since otherwise you need to explicitly consider series obtained by dropping terms, where the $n \geqslant N$ form is directly applicable.

Comment: It is true; $2.5$ is not an integer

Comment: @AhmedHussein Technicality -- take $n=2$, or consider $\frac{\ln n}{n+85}$ if you prefer...

Comment: @ClementC. well yes, but the statement which the OP claims that it is not true is true, and saying that it fails for $n=2.5$ disregards that $n \in \Bbb N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: **yes**.

The precise statement would be:

> If the series with general term $b_n$ diverges, and there exists $N\geq 0$ such that $a_n \geq b_n \geq 0$ for all $n\geq N$, then the series with general term $a_n$ diverges.

(Similarly for the other way, to show convergence.)

*Note:* You can have more general statements involving more delicate conditions, but this is sufficient for most of the cases.